# Higher spec LED near the center of the wafer?

Tags: led

Does anyone know if it is true that chip tolerances are tighter towards the center of the wafer?

There is a vendor that claims that "we pick our LEDs from the center of the wafer".

Because of inherent production variation, LED manufacturers sort the LEDs so you get parts with similar color rank or Vf. But does this have anything to do with where the die is positioned on the wafer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rubbish. Wafers are sliced from a monocrystalline cylinder (called an *ingot*). The monocrystalline nature of the ingot ensures that the properties are the same on any point of the wafer. Yield is the same for chips from the center as from near the edges.

The Lenser document Russell links to should trigger some warning lights. First, there's more technical talk than the common customer cares about. Then why tell all this? Well, having someone pay 400 bucks for a flashlight needs some convincing, and some people *are* sensitive to talk that sounds scientific. The 24 carat gold is also *very* suspicious. 24 carat gold is much more expensive than 22 carat, yet in this application doesn't really performs better. Why do they mention it? Because it sounds good. And you can't check the claims anyway. Only for the gullible?

Comment: I had to laugh at the 6th bullet-point on the manufacturer's site: *"LED light is faster"* (than incandescent). Einstein could learn a lot from this :) Admittedly they go on to talk about turn-on time vs incandescent lamps - although even that claim is stretching the truth. Having said that, my LED Lenser is extremely well built, reliable and *very* bright (and about 25UKP if I remember correctly)

Comment: @stevenh - I see little reason to assume that even if you start with uniform material, you could disregard the possibility of thermal or diffusion differences between a region surrounded by more of the same and one near the edge, or of a radial variation in mechanical operations such as sawing or polishing, or an optical one such as lithography.  Likely they fabrication process has many known issues which are compensated for only to whatever degree is cost effective in the aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

- I don't know if this is true
- I don't think that this is true

BUT

- That is not how it should be done regardless, and anyone advertising this as a criteria for goodness should be at best treated with great care.
- If an LED is "much brighter" it will be reflected in formal lumen/Watt specs which will be reflected (pun almost unintended) in the data sheet.

I am highly suspicious of this claim

> There is a marked difference in LED's and LED Lenser insists on using
>   only patented LumiLEDs, Nichia and Cree LED's taken from the center
>   area of the silicon wafers used in LED manufacture. The LED's from the
>   center of the wafer are higher quality and provide a much brighter
>   light. Naturally, they are also more expensive. [(Source)](http://www.chuckhawks.com/lenser_X7_K3_flashlights.htm)

Note "... more expensive..."

[Repeated here for same brand](http://www.ledco.co.uk/content/Technology-LED.asp)

Same people [different site](http://www.highperformanceled.com/faq)

> No you can’t assume you will have a particularly good flashlight
>   simply based upon what LED is used. LEDs are manufactured on silicon
>   wafers in semiconductor cleanrooms. Due to the nature of the
>   manufacturing process, the LEDs made from the center of the wafer are
>   much higher quality and thus provide much brighter light. Coast™ LED
>   Lenser® LEDs only come from the high quality center of the wafer. In
>   the meantime, the LED manufacturer needs to sell all his LEDs and the
>   lower quality LEDs will end up in someone elses flashlight. Unless it
>   is clearly and completely stated you may not be quite sure what you
>   are getting.) slightly different spiel.

Now, there ARE effects that are diffrent in the centre of wafer than at the edges, they may even produce better devices at the centre. BUT the argument that

> we use LEDs from the centre - do you know where YOUR LEDs come from

can be easily countered with

> "We use LEDs that are 100 % tested and binned by the manufacturer and
>   which meet well established criteria as described in the
>   manufacturer's data sheet - how did YOU say you `chose your LEDs
>   again"

Here's some [real wafer centre effect](http://www.sematech.org/meetings/archives/3d/8510/poster/STS.pdf)- 3rd page

[and here](http://www.semiconductor-today.com/news_items/2010/OCT/DAMILANO_151010.htm)

So what?

---

Because:

LED specs vary extremely widely in many cases.

Some manufacturers who "really know their stuff" can control some parameters tightly.

Even those who can control some parameters tightly must provide "bins" over a substantial range of values.

They only way to be sure of performance is to 100% test for required parameters and this is what reputable LED manufacturers do.

I have been involved in the purchase of several hundred thousand Nichia 'P4' LEDs of one sort in recent years.

Vf at rated current is 2.95 V +/- 0.05V for 99.x% of sample. No binning is needed.

Flux (light output) is binned in 3 bins with 5:3 ratio between extreme ends.
 This is few bins and a tight range compared to most LEDs.

Colour coordinates on CIEE1931 chart are binned in 5 bins. Again, that's a small number compared to most.

Nichia have never ever mentioned "Position on the wafer". And I've never seen it mentioned in any of the literally hundreds of LED data sheets and application notes that I've looked at in recent years. It's reality or not is irrelevant -  reliable quality spec sheets make "why" moot in most cases.

Comment: Your second 'wafer center effects' link is broken

Comment: Some tangential anecdotal evidence that I have from IC processes is that process skew on a wafer usually looks like a gradient across the chip, and not a "bulls-eye". The only way that I think the "wafers from the middle" could be used is in some sort of wafer distributions where many different device sizes are scattered on the wafer. Only the "big" dies are in the center because that's where they fit.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like meaningless marketing babble.

LED manufacturers test every LED made individually, and sort them into "grades" and "bins" accordingly.  Some of the more desirable combinations are sold at a premium, and the less desirable cheaper, especially in bulk.  The manufacturer probably does track where each die came from within the wafer, but that is to track their fab process and spot problems.  Once finished LEDs are binned, I'd be very surprised if this information is recoverable per die.

In other words, what you heard is a load of BS, otherwise known as "sales literature".  For some reason, misinformation and outright fraud seems to be more common with LEDs than other electronic parts.